# Python : Opening local html file on browser without using Webbrowser or Selenium

Tags: python, html, jython

I am using a particular version of Python (v 2.7.0) that doesn't allow me to use webbrowser or selenium libraries.

It also doesn't recognise os.startfile.

Is there another module to use that allows me to open up a locally addressed html file in my browser?

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: It is Python 2.7.0 - cannot update it.

Comment: Which `os` you are using?

Comment: Using Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fumbled on a result by treating it as an exe and project.  Subprocess module worked.  Tested a little further and should work for Jython 2.7.0 also.

```
import subprocess as sp
    sp.Popen(["browser_exe_path","html_path"])
```

Note - if using brave browser - it's exe wasn't recognised.  *chrome_proxy.exe* worked in it's place.

Happy to learn something via feedback.

Comment: Glad that you find the solution. May be you should mark your solution as accepted. I will delete mine!

Comment: Thanks Abdul - we live and learn.  That's the thing when you solve it yourself - it doesn't let you do that straight away - need to wait two days.  But don't delete yours!  It shows a workflow for others to learn from should they come to the same trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using windows you can use `os.startfile` *which will start a file with its associated application.*

```
>>> import os
>>> os.startfile("PATH_TO_HTML_FILE")
```

Comment: Though this works on most versions of python - it doesn't see the attribute startfile in the version I am using.

Comment: @MarkQuinn Ideally it should. Because `startfile` available in the [python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile)

Comment: Ideally yes and it does so on sublime text - but not of the software I require it to work on.